# How do I put a third party website or link to a website to open in a frame on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I am building a website and I want to open a third party website page in a frame on my webpage, what do I use? javascript? If so how do I write it? I am very new and don't know what I am doing.

Comment: <frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_c.htm" />
</frameset>

Comment: Just know that many sites contain "framebuster" code to make sure you can't frame their content.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a dynamic url you can use javascript, otherwise you'll just require an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

```
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to click a link and then show the website in the iframe, it would be like so:

```
<a href="http://site.com/" target="iframe">site.com</a>
<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it so that when a user click on a link, that link open in a certain frame, you should give that frame/iframe an ID. Then you can provide that ID as the target attribute of the anchor.

Lets say your frame looks like this

```
<frame src="somepage.html" id="myFrame">
```

Now you can open a page in that frame like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="myFrame">Some link</a>
```

No need to use anything but plain HTML to accomplish that.

Answer (score -3):

I'd use http://fancybox.net/
It's a light jQuery script that generates a good looking iFrame overlay. You can also use it for pictures and any other overlay.

Include jQuery and Fancybox and FancyBox CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Then add the link:

```
<a id="iframe" href="http://www.example.com/">This goes to iframe</a>
```

And initialize FancyBox using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* This is basic - uses default settings */
    $("a#iframe").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Why load both jQuery, a plugin and additional CSS to create a frame/iframe? Since OP isn't asking about a modal, that seems like a huge waste.

Comment: That is very subjective, and it doesn't even have to be visible that it is a frame/iframe if you don't want to. So to me this is a complex solution to a simple problem.

Comment: maybe, I just wanted to be a help ;)